# Select only specific results in sql (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT id, name::tsvector @@ 'substring1 & substring2'::tsquery
FROM table
```

I have this. The result of this query has 2 fields: id, ?column?
The ?column? field value is true or false.
how can I get only the true results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, name::tsvector @@ 'substring1 & substring2'::tsquery
  FROM table
) AS search
WHERE column = 't'
```

You can also use WITH: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

use WHERE clause.... (if i understand your need correctly)

WHERE condition = true

Comment: The field ?coumn? is generated by the query, it is not contained in a table.

Comment: it doesn't matter - you can still use where. to make it simple you might use AS to give it a short name and use where on the short name.

Answer (score 0):

Add a WHERE clausure to fill this values. Something like this.

```
SELECT id, name::tsvector @@ 'substring1 & substring2'::tsquery FROM table WHERE ?column? = 1 (or True)
```

Comment: The field ?coumn? is generated by the query, it is not contained in a table.

Answer (score 0):

use alias to reference your column

```
SELECT id, name::tsvector @@ 'substring1 & substring2'::tsquery AS condition
FROM table
WHERE condition = true
```